# Ordering algorithm dependent on IF statements

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, sorting

I've got a list of items in my table, with fields `votes_up` and `votes_down` along with others. Now I want to order the items based on popularity which is a function of these two fields. The problem is that algorithm of popularity is dependent on the values of `votes_up`.

For example, if `votes_up` is greater 5:

```
popularity= (votes_up/votes_down)*20
```

If votes_up is greater than 50:

```
popularity= (votes_up/votes_down)*15
```

(I've just used this to explain.. the actual algorithm is different).

Now how can I do this, because normally I would do in my query something like this:

```
ORDER BY (votes_up/votes_down)*20)
```

But I cannot do this right now because what comes after `ORDER BY` is dependent on the value of `votes_up`. Only way I can do this is by:

```
if(votes_up >5){
    p = (votes_up/votes_down)*20;
} else if(votes_up > 50){
    p = (votes_up/votes_down)*15;
}
```

Then in my query I can have `ORDER BY p`.

Now of course this is not valid PHP, but I just want to explain my problem. I hope you understand what I want to achieve.

Comment: You should order the if-s in the opposite order - if votes_up is greater than 50 it will be greater than 5 as well and so you will never enter the `else if`.

Comment: again this is just an example I've used.. the actual algorithm is different.. but that is not the problem.. the problem is how I can actually use the values in the table before querying them... I don't even know how it is possible.. but many famous websites use sorting algorithms that are dependent on the values in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply calculate your popularity using a case statement and then order based on that.  It might look like this:

```
SELECT ((votes_up/votes_down)*(CASE WHEN votes_up > 50 THEN 15 WHEN votes_up > 5 THEN 20 ELSE ? END CASE)) as popularity, [ANY OTHER FIELDS]
FROM table
ORDER BY popularity DESC
```

You never stated what do do with votes_up <= 5 so I just put a `?` for that case, you can fill in the blank.

Note however that this will not be able to utilize an index for this sort, so if you have large numbers of rows you expect to return, your query might perform slowly.

You might want to consider adding a field into the table that stores the calculated popularity value (which would by updated by the application on votes up or down).  You could then index this field and get a more optimized sort.

Comment: Do mean get all the items with the query and then order them using php? is that what u mean by application? The problem with that would be that it would be very expensive if I have like hundreds or thousands of items in the table. Because normally u only query few items in one time.. like for example.. ORDER BY votes_up LIMIT 15

Comment: @user1981248 I actually updated my answer, as I re-read your question and realized you were probably needing to apply the calculation on a row by row basis and not on the entire returned dataset (in which case ordering by just `votes_up/votes_down` would have been sufficient for ordering purposes).

Comment: Thanks.. your are right, I think the best way is to add a field in the table popularity, and that value would change whenever someone votes up or votes down and according to the value of votes_up. Thanks again mate. cheers!

Comment: @user1981248 This is not really related to the question asked, but your algorithm seems problematic to me.  First, you will likely have a divide by zero problem. Second, I don't understand how an item with 10 up votes and 1 down vote would be more "popular" than an item with 10,000,000 up votes and 1,000,000 down votes, yet that is what your proposed sort would produce.

Comment: Like I said in the question.. I just used that to explain my question... but the algorithm I want to use is that of reddit.. which is explained in this article http://blog.linkibol.com/2010/05/07/how-to-build-a-popularity-algorithm-you-can-be-proud-of/ along with other algorithm used by other popular websites